# Exists clause error message on Laravel Validator not working

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-6

I'm working on Laravel 6 and my request message error for `exists` clause is not working at all.

Request:

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'coupon_code' => 'required|exists:coupons,coupon_code'
    ];
}
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'coupon_code.required' => 'is required',
        'coupon_code.exists' => 'not found',
    ];
}
```

I'm sure that the request doesn't pass, and also that the query is done without problem (I log every query and i can see the one done by the validator and it works perfectly)

What should i check? I already do `json_decode($errors)` on my page and it contains any error.

PS: the `required` clause don't works fine also...

Comment: if what you are saying is true, it can only be the input, try to dd($this->all()); in the rules method to see whats in your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a previous `->withErrors([])` that was in conflict with `redirect()->back()` of the validator, don't know why, but after removed it,
no more mistakes have been seen